# How can I push Lotus Notes documents with rich text fields and file attachments to a MySQL database?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

We are using v9.0.1 and have one application that we must preserve for the time being. I am hoping to expose this database's documents with all content to a MySQL database for which we will develop a web front-end to present the records read-only. I know I can export the data to text files or to XML, but I want to retain the formatting of the rich text fields and the files that have been added to them (there are several per document). I've emailed the documents in an agent to a document management system, but the content of the rich text fields is stripped of any formatting and all the data I output is presented in a plain .txt file, but the attachments are preserved. I am hoping to provide a more elegant solution.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Ginni

Answer (score 1):

The Domino router can do rich text to HTML conversion, so if set up properly you won't lose *all* your formatting -- but you still won't get great fidelity. I used that technique in an archiving product that I built 15 years ago, but it was only "good-enough" fidelity, and it was only for Notes email messages. There would be more to do if you're dealing with application documents. It's been too long, so I can't recall any specific details.

If you can spend money on this, the migration tool from Genii Software will help. Look up their AppsFidelity Migrate product. There may be some other third-party products that you could work with, but this one comes from a company that has been 100% dedicated to dealing with Notes rich text for decades. If you call them, tell Ben that I sent you.